# Abrir Área de Trabalho Remota com HTML

Tags: html, windows

Gostaria de saber se tem a possibilidade de abrir o TS (área de trabalho remota) por um meio de um href do HTML.

No site da microsoft existem diversos botões, que se ao clicar ele abre uma janela do explorer, um exemplo é esse abaixo:

[Botão que é possivel abrir o configurações do windows, por meio de um pop-up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhSJL.png)

Comment: No caso seria o TS, não encontrei nenhuma especificação sobre esse tipo de aplicação, pensei que era possível por ser uma aplicação nativa do windows; [Conexão de Área de Trabalho Remota](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FaS3b.png)

Answer (score 3):

É um scheme URI usado em versões atuais do Windows, e claro que exige confirmação por parte do usuário, para chamar as configurações da área de trabalho remota use:

```
<a href="ms-settings:remotedesktop">teste</a>
```

Não é possivel abrir um pop-up e nem controlar isso, é apenas um **atalho** para ser usado no Windows Explorer, e alguns navegadores por conveniência tem suporte a executar tais atalhos em Windows, mas nem todos navegadores direcionam/suportam o esquema `ms-settings:`, o Microsoft Edge suporta, o Firefox também.

Reforço dizendo, não é possível controlar, não é possível ter muitas configurações, apenas alguns atalhos tem algumas configurações.

Segue link da documentação do UWP especifico para esse esquema de URI: https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/windows/uwp/launch-resume/launch-settings-app